# JavaFX: SplitPane Mouse Handling Breaks After Displaying an Application-Modal Stage

Tags: scrollbar, javafx-2, splitpane

Mouse handling on the `SplitPane` and `ScrollBar` controls breaks after displaying an application-modal `Stage`.  The problem goes away after the application window loses and regains focus.  Does anyone know a solution or workaround to this problem?

**In what way is the mouse handling broken?**  When you click and start dragging on the control (`SplitPane` or `ScrollBar`), the control stops responding to your mouse movements *the moment your mouse cursor leaves the control by a single pixel*.  This requires the user to be impossibly precise with the mouse.  You would expect the control to respond to mouse movements, no matter where your mouse cursor happens to be, *up until you release the mouse button*.

The following code exhibits the problem on Ubuntu Linux and JRE 1.7.0_21.  I have seen the problem on other JREs, but I have not tried another OS.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Modality;

public class SplitPaneBug extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button(
            "Move the SplitPane divider, then click here to show the modal"
            + " dialog.");
        button.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler() {
                public void handle(Event event) {
                    Stage dialog = new ModalDialog();
                    dialog.showAndWait();
                }
            });
        button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
        splitPane.getItems().setAll(new BorderPane(), new BorderPane());

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().setAll(button, splitPane);
        vbox.setVgrow(splitPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        primaryStage.setTitle("SplitPane Bug?");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox, 640, 480));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class ModalDialog extends Stage {

        public ModalDialog() {
            Button button = new Button(
                "Click here to dismiss this dialog, then move the SplitPane"
                + " divider again.");
            button.setOnAction(
                new EventHandler() {
                    public void handle(Event event) {
                        close();
                    }
                });

            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            borderPane.setCenter(button);

            initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            setTitle("Modal Dialog");
            setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 600, 100));
            sizeToScene();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's interesting, but what's the question?

Comment: I edited my question to... include a question.  :)

Comment: David, could you provide code of this (as little code, as possible)? This sounds like a bug, and I think, it should be filed in JFX jira. What is JFX version, you use?

Comment: @AlexanderKirov, I supplied the code you requested.

Comment: At least, I cannot reproduce that with 8.0b88 and win7. Will try other builds/OSs later.

Comment: The bug does not manifest on Windows 7 with jdk1.7.0_06 nor on the Mac with jdk1.7.0_17.  This bug appears to be confined to the Linux/Ubuntu platform.

Comment: @AlexanderKirov, does this question (not) deserve an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you use 7u21? Please, set to output VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion().
I don't reproduce on my ubuntu 12.10 with jdk 7u21(b11) downloaded from official site,
but there is known bug in fx 8.0 - https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29576

Comment: Yes, I am sure I am using JDK 7u21, but my Ubuntu is 10.04, so perhaps that is the problem.